# how to set concatenated string parameter in preparedstatement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have the following java code:

```
1- String sql="select * from mytable where params='file_name=?,report_name=?'"
2- stmt.setString(1, fileName);
3- stmt.setString(2, reportName);
```

I get the following exception in codeline 3-:

> Invalid column index

What did I do wrong? how to set params correctly?

Comment: Is param's a string column you want to filter on? Then you could try `"... where params=?"` and `stmt.setString(1, String.format("file_name=%s, report_name=%s", fileName, reportName));`.

Comment: @Thomas yes params is string colum

Comment: Your query doesn't have parameters, it has a string literal containing two question marks. Question marks inside a string literal have no special meaning for the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the bind parameters out of the string literal:

```java
String sql="select * from mytable where params='file_name=' || ? || ',report_name=' || ?"
```

Or, create a single bind parameter and pass in the concatenated value:

```java
String sql="select * from mytable where params=?"
stmt.setString(1, "file_name=" + fileName + ",report_name=" + reportName);
```